# Eroor -TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am learning Angular JS and have the following factory. The data is returned as I can see it when log it to the console.

```js
app.factory('SelectOptionFactory', ['$http', '$q', 'DatabaseService', function ($http, $q, DatabaseService) {

    'use strict';

    //variables

    var routeControllerURL = 'SelectOption/';

    return {
        getSelectOptions: function getSelectOptions() {
            var apiRouteMember = [];
            apiRouteMember.push(routeControllerURL + 'SelectOptionList')
            apiRouteMember.push('APPLICATION_STATUS');
            DatabaseService.getDataFromAPIRoute(apiRouteMember).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Then my controller has the below function which gets called on a button click and I get this error:

```
angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at m.$scope.addInventoryApplicationDetails (Inventory_Controller.js:228)
```

```js
    $scope.addInventoryApplicationDetails = function () {
        $scope.applicationStatus = [];

        SelectOptionFactory.getSelectOptions().then(function (data) {
            $scope.applicationStatus = data;
        }).catch(function () {
            $scope.error = 'unable to get the data';
        });
    };
```

What I am doing wrong as does `.then()` method not return a new promise which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the successCallback, errorCallback?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is being returned from `getSelectOptions()`. You just need to return the promise

```
getSelectOptions: function getSelectOptions() {
        var apiRouteMember = [];
        apiRouteMember.push(routeControllerURL + 'SelectOptionList')
        apiRouteMember.push('APPLICATION_STATUS');

        // return this promise
        return DatabaseService.getDataFromAPIRoute(apiRouteMember).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }
}
```